# Sort a grid with a dynamic field

Tags: acumatica

In the DAC ABONNEMENTL, I add a column "abolnumligne" to sort the grid as the picture.
[image]

I add the "order by" on the PXSelect

```
public PXSelect<ABONNEMENTL,Where<ABONNEMENTL.abonum,Equal<Current<ABONNEMENTL.abonum>>>,OrderBy<Asc<ABONNEMENTL.abonum, Asc<ABONNEMENTL.abolnumligne>>>> CurrentAbonnementl;
```

But I don't know what I must to add in the field :

```
#region Abolnumligne
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Abolnumligne")]

public virtual int? Abolnumligne { get; set; }
public abstract class abolnumligne : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<abolnumligne> { }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Acumatica wiki...The result set returned by the data view is always sorted by the OrderBy clause specified in the type of the data view object. If you sort data records in a different way within the delegate, the result set will be reordered before it is returned by the data view.

In your case, I recommend to create a data view delegate of the Transactions view, and add your OrderBy clause there.